# How do I return just one element from the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have:

```
   @model IEnumerable<SharpTrivia.Controllers.Questions>
   @foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.question)
    </td>
```

It works fine for returning all of the questions
How do I return just one item? Say the one where item.id ==1?

I couldn't get the suggested solution to work, maybe that is because I wasn't clear about what kind of model I am using. I updated my question to give some more details.

Model:

```
   namespace SharpTrivia.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class TriviaModel : DbContext
    {
        public TriviaModel()
            : base("name=TriviaM")
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Questions> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Answer> Answer { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Questions>()
                .Property(e => e.question)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Questions>()
                .Property(e => e.coranswer)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
                .Property(e => e.answera)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
                .Property(e => e.answerb)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
                .Property(e => e.answerc)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Answer>()
                .Property(e => e.answerd)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        }
    }
    }




   namespace SharpTrivia.Controllers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class Questions
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string question { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string coranswer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Html.DisplayFor(i => Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 1))`. And it is not related with *ASP.NET MVC*, it is about *Linq*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you know there's exactly one element, then use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(i => Model.Single(m => m.Id == 1).question)
```

else you should use

```
var item = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 1);
```

and check if item is not null

```
@if (item != null)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.question)
}
```

Comment: I get operator == cannot be applied to operands of type method group and int

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson would you please post (at least the relevant part of) your model? :)

Comment: @PatrikGustafsson not the context - the model of `Questions` - the POCO-class. Your `public class Questions{}`

Comment: I think I added the model now :)

Comment: hmm so it should work - in my project this works... where do you get that exception?

Comment: I get it in the while statement

Comment: I never posted a while statement :D

Comment: Oops, but I think I got it before too. I will try it again.

Comment: Now I get it in @{var item = Model.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 1)}

Comment: in your class, the `id`-name is lowercase, here you write `Id` uppercase. Or just copied from the answere??

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.(and a ; after the expression)

Comment: maybe FYI a little hint: methods, properties and events should be written capitalized to match the C#-coding rules :)

Comment: Tell that to the Visual Studio autogeneraater that got the properties from the database ;)

Answer (score 0):

It is **not recommend** to use **foreach** for only **one item**.
You can use **Break** to loop once as below:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    //Your code block
    break;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't match his requirements for `where item.id ==1`

Comment: I can't find any requirement in OP question where mention item.Id==1 require, it just an example to get only one record

Comment: It works fine for returning all of the questions **How do I return just one item? Say the one where item.id ==1?** He wants to check for a property and not only the first item. If so, your foreach-loop really is unneccessary